# Обход CORS (альтернатива yahooapis)

Tags: javascript, cors

Пользовался канувшей в лету yahooapis для обхода CORS, какие есть альтернативы без использования собственного сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

документация: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation

Пример настройки для jquery:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
        options.url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    }
});
```